# update.packages fails after binaries download

Tags: r

Running R 4.3.1 on Windows 10.  Attempting to update packages throws an error after downloading the binaries and does not install the updates:

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE)

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/xfun_0.40.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 434230 bytes (424 KB)
downloaded 424 KB

Error in if (any(diff)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

traceback()
5: tools::checkMD5sums(pkgname, file.path(tmpDir, pkgname))
4: unpackPkgZip(foundpkgs[okp, 2L], foundpkgs[okp, 1L], lib, libs_only, 
       lock)
3: .install.winbinary(pkgs = bins, lib = lib, contriburl = contrib.url(repos, 
       type2), method = method, available = av2, destdir = destdir, 
       dependencies = NULL, libs_only = libs_only, quiet = quiet, 
       ...)
2: install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, repos = repos, 
       method = method, ..., type = type)
1: update.packages(ask = FALSE)
```

Advice?

Found source of problem.  Anti-virus app BitDefender found and quarantined infected package: acepack.dll is infected with Gen:Variant.Tedy.278833  Deleted acepack package and successfully updated all other packages.

Comment: Can you do `traceback()`?

Comment: Thanks.  I have not used `traceback` before.  Question updated with the output.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to diagnose this further. It must be specific to your setup. Is there something that comes to mind? Maybe some limited user rights, a special kind of network drive involved, some unusual `.libPaths()`, ... It might be worth bringing this to the r-devel email list because I think `checkMD5sums` should guard against an `NA` value there.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comment.  Can you advise on how to notify the r-devel email list?  That org is new to me.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel

Answer (score 0):

Found source of problem. Anti-virus app BitDefender found and quarantined infected package: acepack.dll is infected with Gen:Variant.Tedy.278833

Deleted acepack package and successfully updated all other packages.